# redux-thunk: Property 'type' missing when calling action through store.dispatch()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have found similar issues online but no solution for when calling a `redux-thunk` Action through `store.dispatch()`.

I have the following `action`:

```
export class DBActions {
  static startDatabase(): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, IClientState, AnyAction> {
    return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>, getState: () => IClientState): Promise<void> => {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        dispatch(DBActions.connectDatabase())
        setTimeout(() => {
          let connection: (Connection | undefined) = getDBConnection(getState())
          if (connection) {
            dispatch(DBActions.getImports(connection))
            resolve()
          }
        }, 2000)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

This works without problems when added through `mapDispatchToProps` in a component, but not when directly called inside my `store.ts` after defining a `store`. `store.dispatch(DBActions.startDatabase())` leads to:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction>'.
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: At first glance, your type annotations look correct. Can you try combinations of typing `dispatch` to `Dispatch` from 'redux' and calling via `dispatch<any>(DBActions.connectDatabase())`, or keeping your annotation for `dispatch`, but calling via `dispatch<AnyAction>(DBActions.connectDatabase())`, or even via `dispatch<ThunkAction<...>>(...)`?

Comment: Oh wow, you are right. It really was that simple! `store.dispatch<any>(DBActions.startDatabase())` worked :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: `store.dispatch<any>` looks like a hack rather than a solution IMO. How do you initialize the store?

Answer (score 11):

An easy workaround to avoid the error message - though it is not a solution is:

```
dispatch<any>(DBActions.getImports(connection))
```

Comment: It may be a workaround, but it got me out of a hole. Thank you!

Comment: why using typescript of using `any`?

Comment: que? me no understand

Comment: he probably meant, that `any` disables the purpose of typescript

Comment: Ahhh that's why I said it was a "workaround" and not a solution!

Comment: if you want to use this workaround only in one place: const store = createStore<State, any, {}, {}>

Answer (score 10):

You can extend the `Dispatch` interface of `redux` using [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) of TypeScript. Extend the `Dispatch` interface with a `ThunkDispatch` overload signature. Then `store.dispatch()` method can dispatch async action.

`store.ts`:

```js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk, { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';
import { DBActions } from './action';

declare module 'redux' {
  interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
    <S, E, R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R;
  }
}

const store = createStore((state) => state, applyMiddleware(thunk));

// dispatch async action
store.dispatch(DBActions.startDatabase()).then(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
});

// dispatch sync action
store.dispatch(DBActions.connectDatabase());
```

package versions:

```json
"redux": "^4.1.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
"typescript": "^4.2.4"
```

Answer (score 1):

I fought with this for a while, trying different combinations of typings and could not solve it.

It turns out the issue was because I had `redux@4.0.5` and `redux@4.1.0` installed next to each other.

To fix the issue I just did: `yarn install redux@^4.1.10`, which removed `redux@4.0.5` from my yarn.lock file and resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is correct answer or not. The following is my code:

```
type MyThunkDispatch = ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>;
const thunkDispatch = store.dispatch as MyThunkDispatch;

thunkDispatch(DBActions.startDatabase());
```